# Unable to access a file from code with Xcode - ios

Tags: ios, nsbundle

IOS development...
I have a json data file named "Data.js" in the same directory where the code file is and is trying access it with the following code...

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" odType:@"js"];
```

but this is returning null.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that Xcode isn't putting it in "Compile Sources" by mistake.  It should be listed under "Copy Bundle Resources".

Comment: May be a typo when you wrote this but you put 'odType:' not ofType. I assume this is correct in your code.

Comment: Yeah, you are right that's the typo.

Comment: @borrrden: I tried looking for that option but I could not find that option. By the way I am using Xcode-5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above written answers are right. By default `Data.js file` will be added to the `compilation phase`. You can drag that to the `Copy Bundle Resources phase`. FYI i'am adding a reference screen shot. Go to the settings page of your target under `Build phases` you can find these sections. Drag the selected file to  `Copy Bundle Resources phase`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much Anil. This is solved now. Going further I have issue with reading the data from that file. I will ask for that in a separate thread.  Thanks to all of the respondents!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether Data.js has been added to copy bundle resources under build phases?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you add JS files Xcode will add them to the compilation phase (since they're code files), instead of the Copy Bundle Resources phase. You need to go to your project settings and move it to the right phase.

Comment: Where can I find this option? I tried looking in the project's Build settings but could not find. I am quiet new to this so unable to figure out. PLease let me know the steps.

Comment: Look at Anil's response above. It's in Build Phases, not Build Settings.